# MSBuild WPF Project Failed in WixProject

Tags: msbuild, wix

I need to run MSBuild task in a wixproj, e.g.,

```
<!-- a.wixproj is calling msbuild on a.csproj -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Default">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\A\a.csproj" Targets="Publish" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But when build in VS2010, it failed:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2580,9): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\a.exe'.
```

Whereas it builds OK in commandline using msbuild.exe a.wixproj from the wix project folder. The solution may look like,

```
Solution A
--CSProject A (**a WPF project**)
----a.csproj
--WixProject A
----a.wixproj
```

**I tested and found this happens only when the CSProject is a WPF project, and WixProject doesn't add a referenece to the CSProject. It doesn't when,**

- the CSProject is a console one
- the CSProject is a WPF one, and referenced by the WixProject
- the CSProject is a WPF one, and not referenced by the WixProject but unloaded in VS explorer.

Comment: What is the working directory in the respective cases (wix versus commandline msbuild)? When running from wix, are you sure that the current dir is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MSBuildProjectDirectory` as a reference directory:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\A\a.csproj" Targets="Publish" />
```

Comment: Try adding explicit `OutDir`: `Properties="OutDir=$(WixProjectFolder)\bin\$(Configuration)"`